# Jenkins ssh without password

Tags: unix, jenkins, ssh

In order to automate build on a server, I had to do the following:

1. Make a user with root access on the destination server
2. Add rsa-gen public key to authorised_keys of destination server, for passwordless login.
3. Created script with 1st command being ssh user@dest.

The problem we are facing is that command execution still asks for sudo... How do we achieve this in a script or otherwise?

Comment: How did you give user root access on the server? Can you post your /etc/sudoers file?

Comment: or you can add the pubkey directly to `~root/.ssh/authorized_keys`. +1 for @DanKing question.

Comment: @Misko, I'm guessing they aren't logging in as root but logging in as a user with root priviledges and then executing a command preceded by sudo. There is a way to do this for all, given set or single user, explained [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/192050/how-to-run-sudo-command-with-no-password) but I would really consider why you want to do this because it is definitely a security risk.

Comment: Sure you need to consider the security risk, just wanted to offer a quick alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a plugin to make this simple.

[SSH plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SSH+plugin) can take server details along with credentials and can handle all of it for us.

To use it, follow these steps:

- install SSH plugin on your jenkins from Manage plugins.
- go to configure system, add under SSH remote hosts.
- add all the details required to connect to server
- In your job, add build step - Execute shell script in remote host using ssh.

Comment: link seems broken

Comment: That plugin is containing CSRF vulnerability